# Is there a Twitter API for long message sending?

Tags: iphone, twitter

I'm using sharekit in my iphone app to send text to twitter, but i can't of course send msg longer than 140 characters. Does anyone know a free api for doing this ?

Comment: Twitter doesn't support anything longer than 140 characters. If you want to break a message up, it will be unpleasant for both your users and for their followers. Is there a reason you want to do this? Also, you seem to imply that you have found some "not free" APIs. If this is true, do you mind linking?

Comment: I advise you to read what twitter is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use a third-party service like [TinyPost](http://tinypo.st/706) or twitlonger. Some automatically issue tweets via your twitter account linking to the longer version, á la tinyurl. Good luck!